# Power Automate to schedule the flow after first week of the month on a certain weekday

Tags: power-automate, recurrence

I have a simple thing to do. I have a recurrence flow that refreshes my dataset and then the report goes out based on that.

now my issue that I need to run the flow only on TUESDAYs except the first Tuesday of the month.

[image]

I have set up a trigger condition on the above as below but it's not working. It should have run today but did not.

```
@greater(int(utcNow('dd')),7)
```

[image]

What I suspect is that timezone difference. because my original Recurrence is using +10 timezone but the conditions says utcNow() , maybe it's reading from there and 11am has still not arrived in that timezone. but I need it to run in +10AEST timezone.

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer for it in case anyone else needs it.

The above expression is correct, except that I needed to use **`@greaterOrEquals(int(utcNow('dd')),7)`**

not sure why! but it just works...